# How to pass array value to show in table views laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to make table in view that has value from array in my controller.

Here's my controller:

```
public function Loan Data(Request $request)
{
  $a = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
  $b = array("110", "120", "130", "140", "150");
  $c = array("200", "220", "230", "240", "250");

  $array_all = ['bunga'=>$a,'pokok'=>$b,'pinjaman'=>$c,];
return view('show',[
        'all' => $array_all
    ]);
}
```

how can i pass the array to views that has table like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Data 1</th>
    <th>Data 2</th>
    <th>Data 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Value of array a here</td>
    <td> value of array b here</td>
    <td> value of array c here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to add to your question?

Comment: what about your blade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want something like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Row Title</th>
        
        <th>Data 1</th>
        <th>Data 2</th>
        <th>Data 3</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($all as $rowTitle => $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $rowTitle }}</td>
        
        @foreach ($row as $col)
             <td>{{ $col }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

If you want the data to rotate diagonally, then try something like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Data 1</th>
        <th>Data 2</th>
        <th>Data 3</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($all['bunga'] as $index => $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $all['bunga'][$index] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $all['pokok'][$index] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $all['pinjaman'][$index] }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Comment: but the table pointing sideways, i want it to go down, can you help me?